# differentiate text that is within something clickable into another text (regex, node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I need to differentiate text that is within something clickable into another text.
How do you know that a particular text is a text that appears inside a button or a link tags?
For the below examples, "ButtonName \ LinkName" is the name of the button or the name of the link.

examples:

```
<button><span>buttonName</span></button>another text
<a href="temp.com"><span class="span1"><span class="span2">linkName<br></span></span></a>another text
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Is it allowed to use some sort of DOMParser on the string?